# PHP $_SESSION parameters are reset by server?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have created a *very* basic script to test `$_SESSION` parameters, and on my server this works perfectly:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["favcolor"]))
{
  $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
?>

<br /><br />
<a href="test2.php">Go To Next Page</a>
<br />
<a href="kill.php">Delete Session</a>
</body>
</html>
```

*Page 2* is the exact same, only using a second Session variable, and the kill link does a `session_unset()` and a `session_destroy()`, then redirects to **test1.php**. Again, on *my* server this code works perfectly.

However, the *exact* same code (simply copied and pasted without any changes) on the server of my client does *not* work. Between **test.php** and **test2.php** the session variable set in **test1.php** gets lost. Similarly, going back, the variable set in page 2 is getting lost.

I have been looking at the `phpinfo()` stuff to see if I see clear differences, but I am at a loss here...

Comment: The first thing to look at is whether the session cookie persists correctly on each request. Check the browser developer console. Then you can also check if PHP has write permissions on the session storage path (usually the temp directory)

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a lot of things, but just to start troubleshooting:

This function returns `True` or `False`, depending if it could start the session or not, so maybe you can print this returned value, to check wether it is actually saving the value for you or not.

If not, you surely ran into a php.ini configuration issue and you'll have to check [these values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) on your client's server.

You can check the documentation for `session_start()` at php's [official site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, did not think about testing the session_start this way!

I tested that, and you're spot on, it returns false.

I'll be digging though the php.ini stuff and will update with what I find. At least I have something to go on now :-)

Comment: @Newt `if (\session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    \session_start();
}` try this

Comment: Tried the code snippet: made no difference

Stepped through each of the parameters in the given link and all parameters are identical or have logical differences (like deprecated tags in one are blank, in the other still hold a value) (php version  7.2.33 on the one where it works, 7.3.2 where it does not)

Neither sites have a php.ini file

Still searching for a cause :-)

Comment: correction: the non-working page *DOES* load an .ini file. Not sure if that's the cause...yet

Comment: @Newt Check if the folder where the sessions are being saved (session.save_path in the php.ini file) is writable by the server user, or if you don't know the user it uses, give it 777 permisions. Also check that the session.use_cookies value is set to 1.

Comment: OK got it fixed. 

@leopinzon you were very close. It wasn't the permission, it was 'simply' a completely mis-configured session.save_path

We fixed that, and now it works :-)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a mis-configured session.save_path.

After pointing it to a proper folder, things are working properly